# Error when creating Observer in RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am making an example using RxAndroid as shown below in the code. but Android studio gives the following error:

```
incompatible types
required: io.reactivex.observable <String>
found: void
```

Please let me know how to fix this error

**code**:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
            e.onNext("onNext");
            e.onComplete();

        }
    }).subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String value) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the create and subscribe into different statements:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
        e.onNext("onNext");
        e.onComplete();

    }
});

observable.subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String value) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but i should split it?? i used to use such syntax but with different RxAndroid lib

Comment: Which one exactly?

Comment: compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9

Comment: None of the `subscribe` methods ever returned an `Observable`. They either returned `Subscription`; or in 2.x, some overloads return `Disposable`.